# Redirect variable URL (affiliate links) to index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

I am trying to redirect partner links with google analytics identifier to my index, so that the user is not able to see the variables of the affiliate.

I have tried the following but somehow always nothing is happening

```
RedirectMatch 301 mydomain.de/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=pmediumtype&utm_content=contenttype&utm_campaign=campaignname /$1

Redirect 301 mydomain.de/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=pmediumtype&utm_content=contenttype&utm_campaign=campaignname /index.php
```

The opened URL will look like

```
mydomain.de/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=pmediumtype&utm_content=contenttype&utm_campaign=campaignname
```

I want it to open `mydomain.de` or `mydomain.de/index.php`.

it is also possible that these variable are attached to

> mydomain.de/kategorie/ 
>   mydomain.de/kategorie/kategorie/
>   mydomain.de/kategorie/kategorie/kategorie/
>   mydomain.de/kategorie/articlename.html
>   mydomain.de/kategorie/kategorie/articlename.html
>   mydomain.de/kategorie/kategorie/kategorie/articlename.html

always with these variables behind it

```
?utm_source=deathpurge&utm_medium=partner&utm_content=text&utm_campaign=clan
```

Google url builder [reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en)

Comment: But if you do this redirect in .htaccess then your "partner links" will not be recorded in GA. Is this what you require?

Comment: aren´t they first opened and then redirected?

Comment: No. As soon as the request hits your server, the user will be redirected before any on-page processing. Since GA is reliant on your page loading and the JavaScript being run, it will not be processed. The only way to do this is issue the redirect _after_ your page (and the GA code) has loaded - but the user is likely to see a flash of the original URL, it could be slow and give a bad user experience (not to mention SEO).

Comment: mhh, some freelancer build in a slider which is not working when opening it with link tracking

Comment: Well, you should probably modify your slider instead, otherwise you will lose your "link tracking". It's not obvious why a slider would not work with "link tracking", other than it might also use the query string?

Comment: html text slider on index, I dont see any variables. But the CMS is smarty which always confuses me a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_source=\w+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php? [L,R=302]
```